# How to Store purchases of "N of the same Product" in an Orders table

Tags: database, database-design

So We have our basic tables for the categories, products, and variants of products

**categories**
`id | name | active | parent_id`

**products**
`id | name | price | active`

**c_p_link**
`category_id | product_id`

**variants**
`id | product_id | price | price_override | active | stock`

Which works great.

But I have two queries.

The first being how to structure the orders.

We have an **orders** table
`id | customer_id | ordered | status`

And we also have a **order_products** table
`id | order_id ..?`

this is the one I am curious about.
Say a customer orders 30 of a product. do we

- Add 30 rows, and add the price for each individual item on each row.
- Add one row, add the combined total onto the row
- Add one row, add the individual price onto the row

The next part is, later we are expecting to add voucher support to the cart. e.g. 10% off, buy two, get one free etc. the overall design of this I am not too fussed about right now (this is a couple of months off at least). but I am wondering if that is going to affect which version of the **order_products** table I should choose?

Comment: Why do you not just put quantity in that order_products table ? You can have something like `product id, order id, qty`. You don't need to add price or totals or whatnot if you want to reduce space waste. However, if you need to access those numbers very fast then you may want to include those calculations in the table, but as a rule of thumb it's bad design to include calculations in a database.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur The price may be required to account for specials, discontinuations, inflation, "preferred customer deals", etc. It's only duplicate information if the price is *always the same data* which might be a brittle assumption here. Of course more sophisticated "fully normalized" schemes could be based around Slowly Changing Data.

Comment: Is there any standard to those deals ? You could create a table for deals / promotions and then reference that table if that is the case.

Comment: @pst: Thinking about this I think this would be the kind of design you'd have in a perfect world where you know your promotions long in advance and they are very standard and extremely structured but I don't think that your marketing team would be quite happy with such a structure. I think this the voucher/deal/promotion information could be integrated but in an FYI manner with the price being inserted in the table directly at each purchase. If it's a leveled promotion (10% after 10, 20% after 20...) then you'd have to have an entry for each different price.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur are you referring to not copying the price out from the product or variants table and into the order_products table? Reason is because, if I 3 months later update the product, suddenly all my previous purchases make no sense!

Comment: @Hailwood: Why would that happen ? If you change any information but the primary key, all information will be updated for the orders_product table since they are linked together.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Yes exactly, it would all be updated, But, then if I look at a purchase from three months ago the price showed there will no longer be what they paid.

Comment: @Hailwood: If you have the information written directly into the orders_product table this will not be the case.

Comment: @pst That gives me an idea, what if I stored them all in one row, stored their individual price, and any discounts applied them as an extra product rather than a direct price modification on the product? (much like they get listed on your receipt at the super market) would that make sense to you?

Comment: That is what we have both said...

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur I thought you were saying we **shouldn't** copy the price into the order_products table, bit of miscommunication there.

Comment: That is what I said in my first comment but I changed my mind on my second post which was written 12 minutes ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: *I have never written a database model dealing the "Shopping Carts" or "Orders"*'

---

I think the price *at time of purchase* should be encoded into the purchase data: just like a paper receipt from a store. Let's call this `total_price` which represents each itemized "line" on the receipt and should not be confused with `total_purchase_price`.

That is, *the amount charged is fixed*. It doesn't matter if the product price changes later and changes to prices *should not* reflect in how much was [to be] paid.

Thus I would have these fields: `product`, `unit_price`, `quantity`, `total_price`. A computed column of say, `base_total_price` (`unit_price * quantity`) can be easily added if required.

Now, the `total_price` might be a computed value based on say `base_total_price * precent_discount` field: but, whatever it ends up being, I hold that `total_price` should exist and *should be fixed at time of purchase*. (This implies that, if it is a computed column, all inputs are also fixed at time of purchase.)

Addendum: As stated above, I've never designed a model like this before, but one thing I have observed at stores is discounts being applied as a *negative cost* itemized item. That is, items are bought "at full price" and then the register adds an entry to offset the cost per whatever promotional is occuring. I do not know the merits/reasoning of such an approach.

Answer (score 0):

simply add quantity of product to your order_products table :)

I prefer the 3rd solution, i think it's the best for the performance of your database..

Comment: First, when you add add qty column to your table, you only need 1 row for n qty of same products in one transaction on your database, which means, it will reduce the number of rows.

Comment: This does not answer the voucher/promotion/deal part of the question which is where the difficulty lies.